# How to implement View a User Emoney Mangopay

Tags: php, payment-gateway, laravel-5.7, mangopay

Currency Wise E-money details in Mangopay

I also used $this->api->Users->GetEMoney($UserId);
it provide default currency wise amount.

[Mangopay document code:](https://docs.mangopay.com/endpoints/v2/user-emoney#e895_view-a-users-emoney)

```
GET .../users/:UserId/emoney/
Get Parameters :
{
"Currency": "EUR"
}
```

I am unable to find PHP code to get currency wise converted amount.

Comment: FYI You are looking at the wrong version of the docs, you should be using 2.01 which has changed things slightly (and the PHP SDK docs clearly state you must use 2.01 of the API for the SDK to work - unless you are using an older version of the SDK maybe??). https://docs.mangopay.com/endpoints/v2.01/user-emoney#e895_view-a-users-emoney .

Comment: But still you are correct there appears to be no way to specify the currency parameter in the request.. You would have to amend the GetObject method of [https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk/blob/master/MangoPay/Libraries/ApiBase.php](ApiBase.php) to support an extra parameter, and also lines 107 and 108 to change the generated URL structure to include the query parameter. And lastly amend [https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk/blob/master/MangoPay/ApiUsers.php](ApiUsers.php) to change the GetEMoney function to also accept and pass on the extra currency parameter.